# fitting custom tensorflow layer with conditional operations

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a custom layer in tensorflow that needs to handle conditional branching. Unfortunately, there are several points where this code fails, and I cannot figure out why.

```
class CustomLayer_for_Vu(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):


    super(CustomLayer_for_Vu, self).__init__()
        self.ahp_amp = tf.Variable(initial_value=-65., trainable=True)
        self.threshold_value = tf.Variable(initial_value=-35., trainable=True)
        self.dt = 0.5
        self.a = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.02, trainable=True)
        self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.2, trainable=True)
        self.d = tf.Variable(initial_value=8., trainable=True)
        self.spike_amp = tf.Variable(initial_value=40., trainable=True)

    def call(self, input_arr):
        self.V = input_arr[0]       #corresponds to V[t-1]          
        self.u = input_arr[1]       #corresponds to u[t-1]
        self.I = input_arr[2]


        def subthreshold():
            dV = (0.04 * self.V + 5) * self.V + 140 - self.u
            V1 = self.V + (dV + self.I) * self.dt

            du = self.a * (self.b * self.V - self.u)
            u1 = self.u + self.dt * du

            return tf.stack([V1,u1],axis=0)

        def spike():

            return tf.stack([self.ahp_amp,self.u+ self.d],axis=0)

        def threshold():
            du = self.a * (self.b * self.V - self.u)
            u1 = self.u + self.dt * du
            print(self.spike_amp.shape)
            return tf.stack([self.spike_amp,u1],axis=0)


        def threshold_or_spike():       #need to backset spike value automatically during running
            return tf.cond(self.V<40, true_fn=lambda: threshold(), false_fn=lambda: spike())

        return tf.cond(self.V<self.threshold_value, true_fn=lambda: subthreshold(), false_fn=lambda: threshold_or_spike())


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(),
CustomLayer_for_Vu()])
model.compile(loss=['mae'], optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
```

This code runs just fine during testing, but I cannot fit it onto generated datasets. The input shapes for the dataset are X = [Batch_size,3], Y = [Batchsize,1]. When I try to fit this model to a dataset, it crashes every time.
Here is the code I use for fitting:

```
is_update_model = True
if model is None or is_update_model:
    from keras import backend as K
    print("Building model...")
    model.summary()
    
    
    history = model.fit(x_t, y_t, epochs=50, verbose=1, batch_size=64,
                        shuffle=False, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
    
    print("Done with training!")
```

I am aware that it crashes at two specific issues, the first being the return functions for spike and threshold, as it detects them having different shapes at tf.stack().
The second issue is more general, it doesn't detect gradients for the trainable variables.

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32>)).
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's very confusing what you're trying to do in your layer. what do  self.V, self.u, self.I represent? columns of your passed `x`?

Comment: I am trying to update the value of these three parameters. It receives an input array with elements: [V,u,I], and it needs to output the updated value of V and u.